# image tooltip will not stay margin when is under the middle of the form

Tags: wpf, xaml

so i have an issue where i can't get my image tool tip to stay margin asas i place the trigger under the middle of the form then it will just go up in the top of the form, here the trigger is placed a bit below the middle

[image]

...and here is placed just abit over the middle

[image]

how do you make it stay margin no matter where it placed?

```
<Image x:Name="image_Copy2" Height="27" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="26" Source="img/info.png" Cursor="Hand" Canvas.Left="191" Canvas.Top="480">
<Image.OpacityMask>
<ImageBrush ImageSource="img/info.png"/>
</Image.OpacityMask>
<Image.ToolTip>
<ToolTip Placement="Bottom">
<ToolTip.Template>
<ControlTemplate>
<StackPanel>
<Path  Fill="#FFEAEAEA" Data="M 0 16 L 16 0 L 32 16 Z" />
<Image Height="460" Width="430" Source="img/fælge_dæk/Dæk/Diameter.jpg" Margin="0,-30,20,0"/>
</StackPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
</ToolTip.Template>
</ToolTip>
</Image.ToolTip>
</Image>
```

Comment: Take the margins off your `Image`, except since you have that little arrow on the top I think what maybe you're really asking is how to do something [like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674508/wpf-tooltip-positioning)

Comment: i removed the margin heigth and width and that didn't solved it 
but is not exactly like that since is not for all my tooltips i want that arrow on and i using diffrent images for my image tooltips