# WPF Popup positioning and drawn issues

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup, styles, tooltip

I have a UserControl in which I create an Style that is applied later to the ContentControl of a Popup (below is all defined in the UserControl):

```
    <Style x:Key="ttPopupContent" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <!-- BOTTOM Popup -->
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <Rectangle MinWidth="40" Fill="#fff" Stroke="#FF000000" Grid.Row="1" />
                        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
                            <TextBlock Text="My popup title for bottom popup" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                            <TextBlock Text="My popup body content for bottom popup" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        </StackPanel>
                        <Path Fill="#fff" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Width="20" Grid.Row="0" Data="M 0,21 L 10,0 20,21" />
                        <ContentPresenter Margin="8" Grid.Row="1" />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Placement, ElementName=myPopup}" Value="Top">
                <!-- TOP Popup -->
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                            <Grid x:Name="Grid">
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                                    <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Rectangle MinWidth="40" Fill="#fff" Stroke="#FF000000" Grid.Row="0" />
                                <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="My popup title for top popup"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                    <TextBlock Text="My popup body content for top popup"
                               TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <Path Fill="#fff" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="#FF000000" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
                              Margin="{TemplateBinding Tag}" Width="20" Grid.Row="1" Data="M 0,0 L 10,20 20,0" />
                                <ContentPresenter Margin="8" Grid.Row="0" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

<!-- this label is placed at leftmost of the screen -->
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlck1" Text="ShowInfo" />
<Popup x:Name="myPopup1" AllowsTransparency="True" Opened="Popup_Opened1"
         PlacementTarget="txtBlck1" Placement="Bottom">
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ttPopupContent}"/>
</Popup>

<!-- this label is placed at rightmost of the screen -->
<TextBlock x:Name="txtBlck2" Text="AnotherLabel" />
<Popup x:Name="myPopup2" AllowsTransparency="True" Opened="Popup_Opened2"
         PlacementTarget="txtBlck2" Placement="Bottom">
    <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource ttPopupContent}"/>
</Popup>
```

Sometimes it does not put the arrow pointing correctly to the label at which popup is bound. For example, if I hover on the mouse on label "AnotherLabel" it is drawn as follows (this label is at the rightmost of the screen):

[image]

as you can see the arrow is not placed in the right place. However, I have another label "ShowInfo" that is placed at the leftmost of the screen, then it works:

[image]

So I am trying to adjust the arrow horizontal alignment to point correctly to the label by doing this in code-behind (xaml.cs):

```
    private void Popup_Opened1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement target = myPopup1.PlacementTarget;
        Point adjust = target.TranslatePoint(new Point(8, 0), popup);
        if (adjust.Y > 0)
        {
            popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
        }
        myPopup1.Tag = new Thickness(adjust.X, -1.5, 0, -1.5);
    }

    private void Popup_Opened2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UIElement target = myPopup2.PlacementTarget;
        Point adjust = target.TranslatePoint(new Point(8, 0), popup);
        if (adjust.Y > 0)
        {
            popup.Placement = System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.PlacementMode.Top;
        }
        myPopup2.Tag = new Thickness(adjust.X, -1.5, 0, -1.5);
    }
```

What I am trying to do in code-behind is put the arrow in the correct place by adjusting it horizontally as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17050664/2840305) (in that case is a tooltip, in my case is a Popup).

I have two problems:

1. Adjusting horizontally the arrow to point correctly to the label.
2. The arrow is not drawn correctly, it appears a black line under. See below image:
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `Popup` to conveniently implement the desired behavior.
I suggest to internally set the `Popup.Placement` to `PlacementMode.Custom` to enable custom positioning.
This gives you easy access to the positioning context in order to detect when the placement target is positioned right on the screen (in other words the `Popup` is right aligned with the parent `Window`.

The arrow box and the tool tip content should be hosted by a custom control.

To draw the arrow box properly you should create and draw geometry for example by overriding `UIElement.OnRender` of the custom control.

For simplicity, the following example only supports bottom right placement. You can follow the simple pattern to extend the features to support additional positioning (read comments in code):

```cs
public class MyToolTip : Popup
{
  internal enum Side
  {
    None = 0,
    Left,
    Top,
    Right,
    Bottom
  }

  private MyToolTipContent ToolTipContent { get; }

  static MyToolTip()
  {
    PlacementTargetProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToolTip), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(object), OnPlacementTargetChanged));
    PlacementProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToolTip), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, CoercePlacement));
  }

  public MyToolTip()
  {
    this.ToolTipContent = new MyToolTipContent();
    this.Child = this.ToolTipContent;

    // Enable custom placement to get context related placement info
    // like size and positions.
    this.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = CalculatePosition;
    this.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;

    this.AllowsTransparency = true;
  }

  private static void OnPlacementTargetChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    => (d as MyToolTip).OnPlacementTargetChanged(e.OldValue as UIElement, e.NewValue as UIElement);

  private static object CoercePlacement(DependencyObject d, object baseValue)
  {
    // Backup/delegate original PlacementMode as we need to override it
    // in order to enable custom placement (and to keep it enabled by force).
    (d as MyToolTip).ToolTipContent.Placement = (PlacementMode)baseValue;

    // Enforce custom placement (invokation of the Popup.CustomPopupPlacementCallback)
    return PlacementMode.Custom;
  }

  // Show Popup on mouse hover over the placement target
  protected virtual void OnPlacementTargetChanged(UIElement oldTarget, UIElement newTarget)
  {
    if (oldTarget is not null)
    {
      newTarget.MouseEnter -= OnTargetMouseEnter;
      newTarget.MouseLeave -= OnTargetMouseLeave;
    }

    if (newTarget is not null)
    {
      newTarget.MouseEnter += OnTargetMouseEnter;
      newTarget.MouseLeave += OnTargetMouseLeave;
    }
  }

  private void OnTargetMouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => this.IsOpen = false;
  private void OnTargetMouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) => this.IsOpen = true;

  private CustomPopupPlacement[] CalculatePosition(Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset)
  {
    Side clippingSide = GetParentWindowClippingSide(targetSize);

    // TODO::Handle clipping of remaining sides (top and bottom. Left side will always fit).
    switch (clippingSide)
    {
      // Popup will clip right Window bounds => shift Popup to the left to compensate
      // (i.e. right align with parent Window).
      case Side.Right:
        AlignRightSide(popupSize, ref offset, targetSize);
        break;
    }

    // TODO::Handle remaining modes
    switch (this.ToolTipContent.Placement)
    {
      case PlacementMode.Bottom:
        offset.Offset(0, targetSize.Height);
        break;
      case PlacementMode.Top:
        break;
    }

    // Enforce OnRender to update the visual with the latest instructions
    this.ToolTipContent.InvalidateVisual();

    return new[] { new CustomPopupPlacement(offset, PopupPrimaryAxis.None) };
  }

  private void AlignRightSide(Size popupSize, ref Point offset, Size targetSize)
  {
    offset = new Point(targetSize.Width, 0);
    offset.Offset(-popupSize.Width, 0);
    this.ToolTipContent.HorizontalToolTipArrowAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
  }

  private Side GetParentWindowClippingSide(Size targetSize)
  {
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this.PlacementTarget);
    var parentWindowBounds = new Rect(new Point(), parentWindow.RenderSize);
    Point targetPositionInParentWindow = this.PlacementTarget.TranslatePoint(new Point(), parentWindow);
    var targetBounds = new Rect(targetPositionInParentWindow, targetSize);

    /* Check for clipping */
    bool isTargetRightSideInParentWindowBounds = parentWindowBounds.Contains(targetBounds.TopRight);
    if (!isTargetRightSideInParentWindowBounds)
    {
      return Side.Right;
    }

    // TODO::Check if Popup clips top or  bottom Window bounds following the above pattern. If it does, switch to Bottom/Top placement
    // to make it fit the parent's bounds by changing the OriginalPlacementMode accordingly.
    // If you don't want to overwrite the original value introduce a dedicated property
    // that you really depend on (for example OriginalPlacementModeInternal).

    // Popup completely fits the parent using the desired placement.
    return Side.None;
  }
}
```

**MyToolTipContent.cs**
The custom control to make up the actual content of the `Popup`, responsible for drawing the visual geometries.

```cs
internal class MyToolTipContent : Control
{
  public PlacementMode Placement
  {
    get => (PlacementMode)GetValue(PlacementProperty); 
    set => SetValue(PlacementProperty, value); 
  }

  public static readonly DependencyProperty PlacementProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Placement",
    typeof(PlacementMode),
    typeof(MyToolTipContent),
    new PropertyMetadata(default));

  private const double ArrowHeight = 12;
  private const double ArrowWidth = 12;

  internal HorizontalAlignment HorizontalToolTipArrowAlignment { get; set; }

  static MyToolTipContent()
  {
    DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyToolTipContent), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MyToolTipContent)));
  }

  protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext drawingContext)
  {
    SolidColorBrush fillBrush = Brushes.Transparent;
    var strokePen = new Pen(Brushes.Black, 2);

    // Make room for the stroke
    this.Margin = new Thickness(strokePen.Thickness);

    var toolTipGeometry = new PathGeometry();

   /* Create geometry depending on tool tip position.
    *
    * TODO::Draw different geometries based on different placement.
    *
    */
    if (this.HorizontalToolTipArrowAlignment == HorizontalAlignment.Right
      && this.Placement == PlacementMode.Bottom)
    {
      // "Push" content down to make room for the arrow
      this.Padding = new Thickness(0, ArrowHeight, 0, 0);

      var arrowBoxLines = new PolyLineSegment(new[]
      {
        new Point(this.RenderSize.Width - ArrowWidth, ArrowHeight),
        new Point(this.RenderSize.Width - ArrowWidth / 2, 0),
        new Point(this.RenderSize.Width, ArrowHeight),
        new Point(this.RenderSize.Width, this.RenderSize.Height),
        new Point(0, this.RenderSize.Height),
      }, true);

      var arrowBoxPath = new PathFigure(
        new Point(0, ArrowHeight), 
        new[] { arrowBoxLines }, 
        true);

      toolTipGeometry.Figures.Add(arrowBoxPath);
    }

    drawingContext.DrawGeometry(fillBrush, strokePen, toolTipGeometry);
    base.OnRender(drawingContext);
  }
}
```

**Generic.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MyToolTipContent}">
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="Control">
        <Border Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="My popup title for bottom popup"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
            <TextBlock Text="My popup body content for bottom popup"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" />
          </StackPanel>
        </Border>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```